# Clojure - Postgres No Suitable driver found

Tags: postgresql, clojure

I have defined my postgres database as

```
(def db {:subprotocol "postgresql"
         :subname "//localhost:5432/mydb"
         :user "admin"
         :password "password"})
```

I have also defined a function

```
(defn get-users []
  (sql/query db ["select * from users"]))
```

where sql is `[clojure.java.jdbc :as sql]`

If I run `(get-users)` I get the error

```
SQLException No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/mydb  java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection (DriverManager.java:689)
```

I've seen from other Java posts that I need to load the driver using `Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");`

1) What does this mean?

2) How do I do this/solve my error in Clojure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is to add this to your `:dependencies` in your project.clj:

```
[org.postgresql/postgresql "42.1.4"]
```

Also, while your db definition is fine, instead of the concatenated string for `:subname`, you can also separately define the host, port, and db name, which makes it more modular and composable in case any one of them changes:

```
(def db {:dbtype "postgresql"
         :dbname "mydb"
         :host "localhost"
         :port 5432
         :user "userrole"
         :password "password"})
```

Comment: This answer just jumped the gun on including the `project.clj` in the question as per my comment. It shows a part of what solves the problem, but does not answer the question as stated. Lastly it is padded with irrelevance about `:subname` composability.

Answer (score 1):

This means that the JVM needs to have loaded the Postgres driver class before the driver can be used. The `sql/query` call uses the driver. Usually in Java classes are instantiated, so the class is automatically loaded. But notice that your code has no `new`, nor is a static factory (constructor) method called. With the call to `sql/query` you are in fact directly calling the function `java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection`, without the class `DriverManager` ever having been loaded. Presumably loading `Driver` loads `DriverManager`.

From http://clojure-doc.org/articles/language/interop.html I found this:

```
(Class/forName "java.util.Date")
```

So you could try:

```
(Class/forName "org.postgresql.Driver")
```

Comment: Do I run that in the repl? If so I get the error `ClassNotFoundException org.postgresql.Driver  java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:372)`

Comment: Good to include your `project.clj` in the question, so it can be seen if you have included the Postgres driver jar - which you will need to have put into your maven repo (.m2).